# Expected length of the random interval $(X,Y]$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I have problems proving the next:

Suppose $X,Y$ are random variables in $L_1.$ Then

$$E(X)-E(Y)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}(P(X<x\leq Y)-(P(Y<x\leq X))dx$$ and  the expected length of the random interval $(X,Y]$ is the integral with respect to $x$ of $P(x\in (X,Y]),$ the probability the random interval covers $x.$

I was computing $E(X-Y)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}(x-y)dF_{(X,Y)}(x,y)$ and trying to relate $P(X<x\leq Y)=\int_{\{X<x\leq Y\}}dP;$ similar with the other term, and use Fubini but I don't find the correct way to do this.

Another attempt was utilizing complements of the events $\{X<x\leq Y\},$ $\{Y<x\leq X\}$ and properties of probability measure but that was useless.

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Establish the identity
$$
(X-Y)I(X> Y)=\int I(Y<x\le X)\,dx,\tag1
$$
where $I(A)$ is the indicator of event $A$: it takes value $1$ when $A$ is true, $0$ otherwise. That is, you have to prove that the random variable on the LHS of (1) equals the random variable on the RHS.

Next, establish a similar identity for the case $X<Y$. (The case $X=Y$ contributes zero.) To wrap things up, you can apply Fubini.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!